# How to read header from http::response in Boost

Tags: boost, android-ndk, boost-asio

Trying to use boost for http connection.
So far I have followed the official guide and I was able to get the response correctly and parse the body:

```
 // Send the HTTP request to the remote host
http::write(stream, req);

// This buffer is used for reading and must be persisted
beast::flat_buffer buffer;

// Declare a container to hold the response
http::response<http::dynamic_body> res;

// Receive the HTTP response
http::read(stream, buffer, res);

// Write the message to standard out
std::cout << res << std::endl;

std::string body { boost::asio::buffers_begin(res.body().data()),
                   boost::asio::buffers_end(res.body().data()) };
```

The problem now is that I don't know how to get the header and check the status code. Any help?

Comment: Have you tried using the methods listed in [the documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__http__response.html)? (e.g. `base`, `result`, `result_int`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The status code is not a header, and it's just a property of the response object:

```
std::cout << res.result_int() << std::endl;
std::cout << res.result() << std::endl;
std::cout << res.reason() << std::endl;

for (auto& h : res.base()) {
    std::cout << "Field: " << h.name() << "/text: " << h.name_string() << ", Value: " << h.value() << "\n";
}
```

Prints things like

```
200
OK
OK
Field: Age/text: Age, Value: 437767
Field: Cache-Control/text: Cache-Control, Value: max-age=604800
Field: Content-Type/text: Content-Type, Value: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Field: Date/text: Date, Value: Tue, 23 Jun 2020 16:43:43 GMT
Field: ETag/text: Etag, Value: "3147526947+ident"
Field: Expires/text: Expires, Value: Tue, 30 Jun 2020 16:43:43 GMT
Field: Last-Modified/text: Last-Modified, Value: Thu, 17 Oct 2019 07:18:26 GMT
Field: Server/text: Server, Value: ECS (bsa/EB15)
Field: Vary/text: Vary, Value: Accept-Encoding
Field: <unknown-field>/text: X-Cache, Value: HIT
Field: Content-Length/text: Content-Length, Value: 1256
```

Comment: thanks a lot. what should I do in order to get the fields of the header? Loop through the response and check the delimiters? (e.g. "\r\n\r\n")

Comment: Yeah those _are_ the headers but you didn't ask about that. Expanded my answer. Next time [be sure to check documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__http__response.html) and be precise in your question.

Comment: Docs for [fields](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__http__fields.html) as well.

Comment: I've been using boost for almost 20 years. I find beast is hardly usable for http. I wasn't able to get header values from simple example and from `res` with intellisense suggestions. Total nonsense, had to google for it. The only reason I'm trying to use it is to compare in tests. Otherwise, I'd never use it

Comment: @PavelP Well, I've discovered it, and without intellisense. Yes, some of it was unintuitive (the fact that `message` derives from `headers`  seems the classical mistake of inheritance instead of aggregation). That and the buffer_body is finicky to use correctly. That's the extent of things that I ran into.

Comment: The reason I wanted to compare is because in my unit tests mocked requests that went to localhost for some reason were taking more time that I think they should have taken. I checked time it takes for localhost http server to see incoming data after client sent it 
 (this was with reused tcp connection). To my surprise, libcurl is roughly 3x slower: 40 micro, cppnetlib: 23 micro, beast 13 micro. Receiving from the server takes approximately the same time for all libs

Comment: @PavelP Cool info. Do you write blog posts about this? I'd be interested to read more. [I'm also pretty curious how you accurately measure inter-machine latency]. PS. I also feel I might be able to squeeze some more perf out of the beast implementation, because some of the defaults are not too fortunate :)

Comment: @sehe No, I don't have any blogs. In my tests I don't measure intermachine latency: I tried to measure best case possible scenario sending requests to a localhost server running in the same process. Since it's in the same process I can reliably measure times: before I send a req I read time, when server handler is called, it also reads time. Simple as that. In short, with libcurl whatever it does to send a request it does at least twice more work than passing data through tcp stack on windows.